# Find the coefficients $a_n$,$b_n$ of the Fourier series for a function:

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Find the coefficients $a_n, b_n$ of the Fourier series for the function :

$1 + 5 \sin(3x)+ \cos^2(2x)$

defined on the whole real axis.

I attempted the question, and found that the function could be re-written as:

$\frac {3}{2} + 5 \sin(3x) + \frac {1}{2}\cos(4x)$

I then compared it to the general form of the Fourier series, but my answer was different/wrong.

The answer given for this question (not my attempt) is:

$a_0$ = 3

$a_4$ = $\frac {1}{2}$

$b_3$ = 5

all others are zero.

Comment: Your answer is the same as this I don't understand?

Comment: The answer that I had found was wrong, I have only put the correct answer.

Comment: The answer you have found is correct and agrees with the given coefficients.

Comment: Those are the given solutions, I am not sure how they obtained it. I got up to:
3/2 +5sin(3x) +1/2cos(4x)

But when I attempted finding the coefficients, it was wrong.

Comment: The general Fourier series has form $$\frac{a_0}2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n\cos{(nx)}+b_n\sin{(nx)})$$Hence your coefficients are the same as the supplied answer. You are correct.